# Should I use Future or SchedulerBindings.addPostFrameCallback?

Tags: flutter

When triggering (some necessary) side-effects from a build function, I could either do:

`SchedulerBindings.addPostFrameCallback((_) => ...);`

or

`Future(() => ...);`

Which one is the preferred way and why?

Comment: you mean `Future(() => ...);` not `Future.delayed` ?

Comment: @pskink yes, I am amending